# Select data from one table which is connected to another 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: Emplyees, Jobs and Departments

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the number of emplyees from one department.

I tried something:

```
SELECT count(Emplyees.id) FROM Emplyees 
INNER JOIN Job ON (Job.id = Emplyees.job_id) 
INNER JOIN Department ON (Department.id = 2)
```

but it returns the number of emplyees from all departments.
Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EXISTS clause will allow you to limit by the existence of something without having to worry about whether or not an employee also has other jobs, which will keep your count easy to figure.

Also, since the only thing you need from the department is the id, you can leave that table out and just filter by the dept_id field of the Job table.

```
 SELECT count(id)
 FROM   Employees
 WHERE  EXISTS (
        SELECT      1
        FROM        Job
        WHERE       id = Employees.job_id
            AND     dept_id = 2

    )
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, your solution also works like a charm. Khalid first answered so it's fair to give the accept to him. Do you think your query is more efficient?

Comment: Daniel, I'm not sure which would be more efficient. I suspect mine since his could get multiple records per employee and then need to use the distinct clause on the resulting recordset, but I am not sure. Just as important, however, is which you find easy to read for when you need to edit it later.

Comment: If you like them both the same, vote for the first one in I would think.

Comment: Your solution seems to fit better to my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE` clause to filter out department,where clause will apply for the whole result set returned by joins,while condition in on clause will filter result from joined table only

```
SELECT count(e.id) 
FROM Emplyees e
INNER JOIN Job j ON (j.id = e.job_id) 
INNER JOIN Department d ON (j.dept_id =d.id )
WHERE d.id = 2
```

And also use `DISTINCT` in count so if any employee has applied on multiple jobs that belong to same department will be counted as 1 i.e `COUNT(DISTINCT e.id)`

Comment: Thanks alot M Khalid Junaid